# What's the difference between the 'oriental market building' and the regular 'small market building'?

Tags: anno-1404, anno-1404-venice

When one starts an oriental island you can begin placing **Oriental Market Buildings**, which function like the Occidental **Small market building**.  The biggest difference I can tell is that the Oriental Market Building costs more and you can't upgrade it.

What is the difference between the two?

When do you use one or the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't say it functions just like a Small market building, as it have 3 carts, instead of 1. It functions almost exactly as the Large market building, but more cost efficient.

As you can see from [this table](http://anno1404.wikia.com/wiki/Building_comparisons#Warehouses), the Oriental market building has a few advantages against the Large market building:

- Lower building cost (the Large market building also needs stone and glass), and
- Lower maintenance cost (25 instead of 30)

I would recommend using the Oriental market building, when you are in need of more than 1 cart, as it is cheaper to build, than upgrading the small market building.